# Big-Oh complexity of multithreaded code

Tags: concurrency, time-complexity

How is the running time of algorithms that are affected by multithreading specified?

For example, a CompareAndSet loop may never be satisfied (if you're very very unlucky)

```
AtomicReference<ContainerOfItems> oldContainer;

void AddItem(Item aItem)
{
    ContainerOfItems newContainer;

    do
    {
        newContainer = null;
        newContainer = new ContainerOfItems();
        newContainer.CopyContents(oldContainer);
        newContainer.Add(aItem);
    }
    while (!CompareAndSet(oldContainer, newContainer));

    oldContainer = null;
}
```

In this example (which looks a lot like Java but really is pseudocode) the CopyContents
operation could take a long time, such that oldContainer has been replaced by some other thread causing the `CompareAndSet` to fail. What's the running time of this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the running time of this code?

The overall runtime of your program depends highly on how long `copyContents(...)` takes and a prediction on how often there are going to be race conditions that cause the `compareAndSet(...)` to fail.  This will depend on how many threads are running at the same time.

However, I suspect that in terms of Big-O, the number of times looping because of `compareAndSet(...)` does not matter.  For example, if a `copyContents(...)` takes O(N) time to run, on average it has to loop 3 times to complete the `compareAndSet(...)`, and you run it N times to add all of the items, the it is O(N^2) -- the 3 drops out because of the constant.

Also, because you are implying concurrency, there will also be a factor speed improvement because the algorithm will be multi-threaded, but that too will only be a constant factor improvement and not affect the Big-O.  So the Big-O can be calculated by looking at the Big-O of `copyContents(...)` times (I assume) N.